# wxPython font sizes are inconsistent for different widgets. How to fix?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxgrid

Setup:
wxPython 4.0.7 + Python 3.8.6 + Kubuntu 20.10 (Default Breeze theme)

wxPython Demo downloaded from - https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.1.1/

In the image below it can be seen that font sizes are inconsistent across different widget areas. Some places the font is normal sized as per OS configuration. Whereas in some areas its very small.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

[image]

The same problem is happening in my application as well.

Note:
Earlier I was using KDE Settings > Display Configuration > Global Scale greater than 100%. I tried setting it back to 100% but that did not help either.

Comment: Does the theme you use for the desktop, affect the font size for different widgets? Try a few different themes, to see if it's a generic issue or theme dependent.

Comment: @silvermoon, what os? What theme? What wx version? Is it reproducible in c++ or wxpython-specific?

Comment: @Igor Setup: wxPython 4.0.7 + Python 3.8.6 + Kubuntu 20.10 (Default Breeze theme)

Comment: @SilverMoon, this might be OS/theme specific. Try to use different theme or test on another Linux distro or even on Windows. There is nothing specific wxWidgets doing in terms of setting fonts/colors/etc. Also, see if the same behavior is in C++ - mainline wxWidgets.